# Why is there subject auxiliary inversion in the embedded clause in "I wonder could we untie him"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, subject-verb-inversion, pragmatics

I was reading the book *The Chronicles of Narnia: The Lion, the Witch and the Wardrobe* and there is a sentence from it I found quite strange:

> "I wonder could we untie him as well?" said Susan presently. But the enemies, ....

Why is there a subject-auxiliary inversion in the embedded clause?

Is it something to do with **garden path**?

Comment: I would think it's more an attempt to mimic spoken English; in written language you'd probably write it as _I wonder, could we untie him as well?_. Garden path sentences lead you to an alternative interpretation of a sentence which is invalidated later on, which isn't the case here.

Comment: @OliverMason Thanks for your explanation. I understand that there is a difference between oral language and written one.

Comment: @jlawler I see. Thanks for providing the source. I think it has solved my question.

Comment: I'd probably insert a comma or colon after "wonder". Another way of expressing the same idea would be "Could we, I wonder, untie him as well?"

Comment: Thanks Oliver Mason. I understand that it is in spoken English.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan Thanks very much for providing an alternative case here. Yes, I agree that we would normally insert a comma or colon after "wonder".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seriously doubt C. S. Lewis would make a typo. This is indeed spoken language, but it is also standard in some dialects. Yale University has an article on *[Inversion in embedded questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/602321/why-is-there-subject-auxiliary-inversion-in-the-embedded-clause-in-i-wonder-cou/602596#602596)*, commenting on examples such as

> And he told them who was it. (Fought 2003:98)

The article says

> In the syntactic literature, this construction is discussed in some detail by McCloskey (1992) for *Hiberno English* and Henry (1995) for ***Belfast English***. It has been reported in a number of *North American English varieties* as well, including African American English (Green 2002:87-89), Appalachian English (Wolfram and Christian 1976:129), Chicano English (Fought 2003:98), Northeast U.S. English (Ross 1975) and Newfoundland English (Clarke 2004:315). This construction has become rather widespread, according to the following passage from Wolfram and Schilling (2016:388):
>
> > [...] the use of inverted word order in indirect questions, as in
> >
> > - She asked could she go to the movies,
> >
> > is becoming just as much a part of informal spoken American English as indirect questions without inverted word order, as in
> >
> > - She asked if she could go to the movies.

Quoting, *Shane Walshe, Irish English as Represented in Film, 2009*,[Thought.co](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-an-indirect-question-1691162) also signals dialectal usage:

> Some dialects of English (including ***Irish English*** and ***Welsh English***) retain the inversion of direct questions, resulting in sentences such as
>
> > I asked him was he going home.

Now, [C. S. Lewis was born in Belfast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C._S._Lewis), so it's not surprising he uses this structure.

Comment: Wow thanks @fev

Comment: The literature you have recommended on the text is awesome! I didn't know there is a well formed phenomenon and the dialectical difference is very surprising to me. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

The words "I wonder" cannot be part of the question, precisely because only the clause starting with "could..." has undergone subject-auxiliary inversion.

This is likely either a typo or a nonstandard informal usage. Typically you would see either:

> I wonder: could we untie him as well?

Or:

> I wonder if we could untie him as well.

Comment: well put! thanks!

Comment: [This 'version' {Todd Anderson; Sermon Central}](https://www.sermoncentral.com/sermon-illustrations/22754/he-led-them-up-the-steep-slope-out-of-the-river-by-todd-anderson) uses a quotative-like structure]: << I wonder, could we untie him as well? Said Susan presently.>> (Admittedly, other punctuation in the sentence is iffy.) I'd write << "I wonder – _could we untie him as well?_" said Susan presently. >>

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thanks for the literature.